# Passing an array parameter of a function to another function used within the previous function

Tags: c

So I'm rather stumped on why my code isn't working. I have 2 functions, one that adds numbers and the other gets the average. Thinking that I might as well as call the add function within the average function to save a few more lines of code, I tried it out.

Also, they both have an array as their parameter. The array has a size of 5 and is set to float.

```
float addOp(float num[])
{
    int i;
    float ans;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        ans += num[i];
    }

    return ans;
}

float aveOp(float num[])
{   
    float average;

    average = addOp(num) / 5;

    return average; 
}
```

The add function works perfectly but when I try to use the average function, the code runs but the answer it gives out is way off. I'm thinking that C doesn't allow passing arrays in succeeding functions but I'm not very sure. Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should initialize `ans = 0` in addOp. Otherwise it can take whatever value is on the stack at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is addOp()

```
float addOp(float num[])
{
    int i;
    float ans; /* This is uninitialized */

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        ans += num[i];  /* This adds an undefined start point to the 5 numbers*/
    }

    return ans;
}
```

The fix is to change to

```
float ans = 0;
```